# Javafx ThreeView Manual Settings Selected

Tags: javafx

I have a view, using TreeView as a tree view display. I want to manually set a child node as the selected state. How should I set it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [mcve] and edit your question

Comment: read the api doc (you want to look for selectionModel) and a good basic tutorial about using fx controls (the info page of the javafx has references)

Answer (score 0):

`TreeView` selections work basically the same as `ListView` selections, as long as you ignore indices. Just pass the `TreeItem` you want to select to the `select` method of the selection model:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TreeItem<String> c1 = new TreeItem<>("child 1");
    TreeItem<String> c2 = new TreeItem<>("child 2");
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("root");
    root.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);

    TreeView<String> tv = new TreeView<>(root);

    // select c2
    tv.getSelectionModel().select(c2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(tv);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```